# QtCreator C++ - Checkbox

Tags: c++, qtcreator

Хочу написать простенькую программку с помощью `QtCreator` на `C++`
Создал ивент, которые должен при клике на кнопку, придавать ей свойство `true`. Это мой первый опыт с  `С++` и `Qt`, объясните пожалуйста подробно что и как, я делаю не правильно и почему данный код не работает, ведь я выбираю объект и дальше пытаюсь присвоить ему `true`

Имеется такой код:

```
void MainWindow::on_poweButton_clicked()
{
    QCheckBox powerCheck;
    powerCheck::setChecked(true);
}
```

Comment: А вопрос-то в чем?

Comment: @nick_n_a в GUI они уже заложены.

Comment: QCheckBox - это кнопка, а где она находится, может её надо связать с формой как-то по ай-ди или по имени? Тут похоже что она обьявлена просто как локальная переменная.

Comment: @nick_n_a http://prntscr.com/cibwhb вот так выглядит в GUI. Это мой первый опыт с C++, я не знаю как их соединить и что QCheckBox по вашему является кнопкой.

Comment: Первый опыт в C++ сразу с GUI на Qt решили получить?

Comment: @alexolut именно так, хотелось бы понять, как взять этот объект powerCheck и изменить его свойства.

Comment: @Insider не стоит основы языка начинать изучать сразу с GUI, потому как Вы просто будете тыкаться вслепую, не понимая что происходит.

Comment: @alexolut окай, буду изучать по книге. но могли бы вы сейчас написать пример, как по клику на кнопки изменить этот checkbox?

Comment: @Insider обращаться надо к **существующему** элементу формы, скорее всего через `ui->`, если Вы в графическом редакторе форму рисовали.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш код создает временную кнопку и делает её нажатой. Кнопка не добавляется на форму и удаляется после выхода из функции.

```
void MainWindow::on_poweButton_clicked()
{
    QPushButton*powerCheck=dynamic_cast<QPushButton*>(QObject::sender());        
    powerCheck->setChecked(true);
}
```

При создании кнопки надо добавить setCheckable(true)

Comment: получаю ошибку Cannot convert 'QPushButton* to CheckBox*' in initialization QCheckBox *powerCheck=dynamic_cast<QPushButton*>(QObject::sender());

Comment: малясь опечатка QPushButton*powerCheck

Answer (score 0):

Предположу что вы хотели сделать что-то вроде этого:

```
#ifndef WINDOW_H
#define WINDOW_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QCheckBox>

class Window : public QWidget{
    Q_OBJECT
    QCheckBox *_checkBox;
    QPushButton *_pushButton;
public:
    Window(QWidget *parent = 0):
        QWidget(parent),
        _checkBox(new QCheckBox("Чек бокс")),
        _pushButton(new QPushButton("Кнопка"))
    {
        QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
        layout->addWidget(_checkBox);
        layout->addWidget(_pushButton);

        connect(_pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(_setCheckBoxChecked()));
    }
private slots:
    void _setCheckBoxChecked(){
        _checkBox->setChecked(true);
    }
};

#endif // WINDOW_H
```

Настоятельно вам рекомендую сначала изучить С++, перед тем как изучать Qt, это сэкономит вам кучу времени